# Qual a maneira correta de salvar um IP no banco de dados?

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, tipagem

Como salvar os dois tipos de IP o IPV4 e IPV6, em um banco de dados MySQL? Qual a tipagem correta e o tamanho da coluna? Alguma outra observação?

Recebo o IP através do `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` com PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Existe funções para usar no IPV4.

Para endereços IPv4, você pode querer armazená-los como um `int unsigned` e usar as funções `INET_ATON()` e `INET_NTOA()` para retornar o endereço IP do seu valor numérico e vice-versa.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-ntoa

Para IPv6:

Usar esse tipo  `VARBINARY(16)`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet6-aton